# .net core Worker Service iterate n times before gracefully stop without ctrl+C

Tags: background-task, .net-core-3.0

What I am trying to achieve is running an async task n times and then gracefully finish without having to do ctrl+C. I believe I need to use IHostLifetime, since CancellationToken stoppingToken is read only

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifeTime)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            //Running task
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error");
        }            
    }

    public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Worker stopped at: {DateTime.Now}");
        base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Worker disposed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

There are not much documentation regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already accepts [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) as its third service. You can call `StopApplication()` when you want the host to terminate.

The `StopAsync` method is dangerous though - it says the service has stopped even though the *base* `StopAsync hasn't. [*That's* the method](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L49) that will signal the service's cancellation token, so this can have unexpected consequences. It should be changed to :

```
public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Worker stopped at: {DateTime.Now}");
    return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

or, better yet :

```
public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    _logger.LogInformation($"Worker stopped at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

The `cancellationToken` argument is signalled when the shutdown period expires and the services need to terminate immediatelly. It's not used by `BackgroundService` itself, it's passed to the overriding `StopAsync` implementations